# Angularjs Pass form which is inside modal controller to ng-controller outside modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I am a bit confused as to why this doesn't work:

My main Angular page has an ng-controller called "SearchCtrl" which contains a bunch of logic for sending searches to a webserver.

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$http','$scope', function($http,$scope) {

$scope.doAlert = function() {
    console.log('search page alert inside searchresultsctrl');
}
```

This controller is included on my search page,and then somewhere down the page there is another controller, SearchSortModalCtrl, which will pop open a modal and let users do some stuff:

```
app.controller('SearchSortModalCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
.....

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/modal-search-sort.html',
        controller: 'SearchSortFormCtrl',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });
```

That is connected to this controller:

```
app.controller('SearchSortFormCtrl', ['$http','$scope','$rootScope','$modalInstance', function($http,$scope,$rootScope,$modalInstance) {

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    };

    $scope.doAlert2 = function() {
        console.log('search page alert test2');
    }
```

So anyhow, what I am trying to do is to put an ng-submit inside the modal form, and when that form is submitted, it will do some logic on the SearchCtrl.

But if I do

```
ng-submit="doAlert()"
```

inside my modal, it will not work or send anything to SearchCtrl, but if I change it to doAlert2() it will of course run on the SearchSortFormCtrl. I tried making it

```
ng-submit="$parent.doAlert()"
```

but no dice and to show you what level I'm flailing away on I even tried

```
ng-submit="$parent.$parent.doAlert()"
```

and that did nothing.

What am I doing wrong, or how can I get this form to just do stuff in the SearchCtrl?

Comment: Can you show your html. is `SearchCtrl` structured in the parent heirarchy? If so you can provide a `scope:` option in the modal settings. Ex `var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/modal-search-sort.html',
        controller: 'SearchSortFormCtrl', scope:$scope,...`

Comment: Okay so I am not sure what structured in parent hierarchy means exactly, but basically the SearchSortModalCtrl html tags are completely enclosed by the SearchCtrl, if that's what you mean. So if I include scope:$scope in the modal settings, then $scope.whatever will refer to SearchCtrl's $scope?

Comment: Oh yes I tried this and it does work perfectly. If you submit it as an answer I can mark it as the approved solution, and huge thanks also!

Comment: If that is the case your controller should automatically have the function inherited (to verify that try calling it from `SearchSortModalCtrl`). So you could just set the scope option by creating a child scope of your controller scope `scope:$scope.$new()`

Comment: Sure added as answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your controller is a child controller of `SearchCtrl`, any of its descendants (except for isolated scoped directives) will automatically have `doAlert` function inherited. In your case you are not using `scope` option in modal settings so the modal scope will ultimately be  `$rootScope` which angular ui modal does. You can provide a scope option in the settings from the controller. So:

Either set `scope:$scope` or if you do not want to pollute current controller scope with properties set by modal controller set a childscope, i.e `scope:$scope.$new()`.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/modal-search-sort.html',
    controller: 'SearchSortFormCtrl',
    size: size,
    scope: $scope, //Or $scope.$new()
    resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
    }
});
```

[Documentation link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

> scope - a scope instance to be used for the modal's content (actually the $modal service is going to create a child scope of a provided scope). Defaults to $rootScope

Comment: I'd suggest to avoid using explicit $scopes reference, since angular 1.2+ supports controllerAs syntax. That one could be solved with a shared service, for decoupling both features.

Comment: @Werlang oh well what OP has is not controllerAs syntax. He is just using direct `$scope` binding. But according to me decision of a shared service cannot be just said without knowing more details.  And you do not always have to use/create shared service just so you need to invoke a method in another controller, pub/sub or event bus will be much better approach.